# Python: most succinct way of counting even digits?

Tags: python

This question derives from an exercise in the book [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/howtothink/latest/howtothink.pdf) which my girlfriend and I are using to teach ourselves Python. You're supposed to write a function to count the number of even digits in a given integer number. Zeroes are not to be counted. My girlfriend went the while-modulo-integer-division path and I went the int-to-str-to-int-modulo-path.

After chatting about the exercise with my colleague (we're both mostly users of Ruby), he came up with this solution:

```rb
number.digits.count &:even?
```

... that's 27 bytes flat, excluding putting it in a function.

<strike>My Python solution:</strike>

```py
e=0
for c in str(number):
    d=int(c)
    if (d!=0) and (d%2==0): e+=1
```

... weighs in quite heavily at 65 bytes (and is slow, because of the string conversion, but probably comparable to its Ruby counterpart, although I didn't check).

The solution given by _@iz in the comments:

```py
sum(c in "2468" for c in str(number))
```

... comes very close at 37 bytes. Is it the shortest possible way of solving the exercise, or is even less possible (while keeping the name of the variable `number` the same)?

Comment: `sum(c in "2468" for c in str(number))`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Give me the best code” is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: @iz_ Reads like an answer to me!

Comment: @Prune: "give me the best code" is significantly less specific than what I'm asking and is a demand, not a question.

Comment: Slightly faster to go `sum(map("2468".__contains__,str(number)))` at the cost of some bytes.

Comment: Are you aware of the Code Golf SE? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for that hint, @bers! Should I delete here and re-open there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

In my previous solution I forgot that "Zeroes are not to be counted.". Also the `ord` function won't give you an error if it's not an `int`.

I updated my answer considering the @bers comments.

You could write the something like:

```
sum(1 for n in map(int, "0123456789") if n and not n % 2)
```

If readability is not at stake we could go even shorter:

```
sum(~n%2 for n in map(int, "0123456789") if n)
```

It's important to note that you have to make number postive before converting it to `str`.

Shorter is not always better (it could lead into code obfuscation) but this is a coding challenge, anyways.

**Previous answer:**

I think using the [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#ord) function would be a good solution:

```
sum(1 for number in "0123456789" if ord(number) % 2 == 0)
```

In any way you have to filter out the odd numbers.

Edit:

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement on [iz_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10611983/iz)'s solution in 34 bytes:

```py
sum(c in"2468"for c in'%s'%number)
```

Python has no problem with quotes being directly next to functions/keywords as it's still able to parse them out. It then uses [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) (also known as old string formatting) to convert the number to a string.

My own further improved solution in 33 bytes (but may give a SyntaxWarning depending on the interpreter):

```py
sum(~ord(c)%2for c in'%s'%number)
```

When you take the bitwise not of a number, this will always result in the one's bit being flipped, so it will always have a flipped value when you take %2. You could achieve the same thing by doing `ord(c)%2<1` but the bitwise not saves an additional byte.